# Wacom stu-430 signature is captured too slowly

Tags: javascript, digital-signature, electronic-signature, wacom

I'm having problems configuring my Wacom tablet signature. I did the example without problems, but when I integrated it in my program, it broke.

The problem is, when I click on the "Sign" button, it takes 5-10 seconds until the signature capture is shown. After this, it runs OK.

I didn't make many changes on the example; this is a part of the code I've modified:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var boton_firma = $('.captura_wacom');
        boton_firma.prop('disabled', false);
        boton_firma.on('click', init_firma);
    });
})(jQuery);

function init_firma() {
    var signatureForm = new SignatureForm($(this).parent().find('.fichero_firma').get(0), $(this));
    signatureForm.connect();
}
```

When I pause the process, it always stop in a js include from wacom called `BigInt.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I commented out one part of `demobuttons.js` (wacom example), and it runs ok now without waiting

The line is marked (`<---`) in the example below:

```
try {
    if (m_usingEncryption) {
        //m_tablet.startCapture(0xc0ffee); <---
    }
} catch (e) {
    m_usingEncryption = false;
}
// Enable the pen data on the screen (if not already)
m_tablet.setInkingMode(0x01);
```